# Sharing an array of structs using mmap

Tags: c, arrays, struct, mmap

I am trying to create an array of structs that is shared between a parent and child processes. I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to access the array data.

I feel certain that the problem has something to do with the way I'm using pointers, as this is an area I'm not very comfortable with.

Please note that I edited out most of the code that didn't seem relevant.

```
/* structure of Registration Table */
struct registrationTable{
    int port;
    char name[MAXNAME];
    int req_no;
};

main() {

    /* the registrationTable is to be a shared memory space with each child
    process able to access and update. No concurrency controls are 
     implemented. The parent process is responsible for cleaning up after
     the kiddies.
 */
struct registrationTable base_table[REG_TABLE_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < REG_TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
    base_table[i].req_no = 0;
    memset(base_table[i].name, '\0', MAXNAME);
    base_table[i].port = 0;
}

printf("\nMapping Shared Memory\n");

//set up shared memory space
//void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
    //              int fd, off_t offset);
//      addr = NONE, prot = PROT_NONE, flags = MAP_SHARED 
struct registrationTable *table = mmap(base_table, sizeof(base_table),
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                        MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                        -1, 0);

while(1){
    pid_t child = fork();

    if (child == 0) {//is child

        for(int i = 0; i < REG_TABLE_SIZE; i++) {

            printf("\nExamining table looking for client at %s port: %d\n", 
                    packet_reg.data, clientAddr.sin_port);

            printf("\ntable[1].req_no: %d", ta[i].req_no);

                            //segmentation fault on next line
            if (strcmp(table[i].name, packet_reg.data) == 0 
                    && table[i].port == clientAddr.sin_port) {
                table[i].req_no++;
}
```

Comment: What did your debugger say?

Comment: @H2CO3 I haven't run any debugger, since this is a network application I am not sure how to go about using a debug tool. The error return is `segmentation fault`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized content of the `table` after it was allocated by mmap. So it contains garbage. And so `strcmp(table[i].name, packet_reg.data)` has a great chance to go over allocated buffers and access e.g. non-allocated memory.

1. initialize table properly;
2. use strncmp for the comparison there.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I should initialize `table`? I did initialize `base_table` and `table` should point to the same segment of memory. To clarify: I tried to write a value to the shared memory after calling mmap and I got the same error (seg fault). thanks.

Comment: `base_table` has nothing to do with that `table`, these are different objects.
According to mmap man: "If addr is not NULL, then the kernel takes it as a hint about where to place the mapping; on Linux, the mapping will be created at a nearby page boundary.  The address of the new mapping is returned as the result of the call." 

So you shall call mmap and invoke that initialization code you have for base_table but for the table instead.

Comment: yes, very good point, and I completely missed that the memory address returned is different. However, the man page does say that when using `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, the values are initialized to 0. My main problem was that I was using `PROT_NONE` when I needed `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE`. If you can amend your answer to mention this, I would like to accept it. thanks.