# Sharing a vector with mmap in C

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory, mmap

I'm able to send a structure through shared memory, but what if I want to send myStructure[SIZE]??

I'm trying this with a vector of integers. And my problem starts on the writer here:

```
int fd, data_size = VECSIZE*sizeof(int), i, numbers[VECSIZE];
int *number;

fd = shm_open("/ex02_1100620", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

ftruncate(fd, data_size);

number = numbers;

srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    number[i] = rand()% SIZE + 1;
}

number = (int *)mmap(NULL, data_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Now if I do something like:

```
number = numbers
```

and then print `number[SIZE]` positions it works, but if I print `number[SIZE]` after the mmap it prints all 0 and does the same on the reader.

I do that but I think catching the errors to explain my problem isn't really necessary.

I've read this post [Sharing an array of structs using mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649421/sharing-an-array-of-structs-using-mmap) but couldn't understand what I'm doing wrong.

If you need more information on the code just say it.

Comment: Um, the writer here isn't writing anything to the shared memory?

Comment: That's where I'm having problems. Should I just use number and forget about numbers?

If that's the case shouldn't I use malloc instead of doing number = numbers? And how would that work with the mmap call?

Comment: I mean it's not writing anything to the shared memory *because you didn't tell it to do that* - you set `number` to point to `numbers`, then write a bunch of numbers through `number` (so, to the `numbers` array), then you map some shared memory and set `number` to point to the shared memory. At no point did you actually write to the shared memory.

Comment: Oh ok! That makes sense!!! Sorry this is my second exercise :S

But about the memory space that I reserve with number = numbers, should I use malloc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's review what your program does:

- Create/allocate an array of `int`s called `numbers`.
- Set `number` to point to `numbers`.
- Write a bunch of numbers through `number` - because it's pointing to `numbers`, this is the same as writing to `numbers` directly.
- Map some shared memory and set `number` to point to the shared memory.

What you actually want to do is this:

- Map some shared memory and set `number` to point to the shared memory.
- Write a bunch of numbers through `number` - because it's pointing to the shared memory, this is the same as writing to the shared memory directly.

Hopefully this is enough information to fix your code.

(Note that since the shared memory doesn't have a variable name, you can't write to it directly - that's why we use a pointer)

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks for the answer, was a dumb mistake of mine...

And I understand now that my second question about malloc is kind of stupid because you also need to allocate some shared memory...it really helped. Thanks a lot.

Comment: (I changed "allocate some shared memory" to "map some shared memory" since it seems more accurate; but I don't know that much about how shared memory works on Linux)